# SQL Selecting ONLY products that are available in every location

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, relational-division

I'm trying to combine these queries with subqueries to select products that exist in every location in the store_location table. There are multiple tables in this schema but the most relevant ones are Product, Sells, Sizes, and Store_Location. Sells is the table that holds both product_id and store_location_id. Sells can therefore be joined to store_location (in a subquery?)

I've learned how to do aggregates, and it seems like I need a count of the number of locations, but how can I use a comparison in the where clause to filter out products that aren't available everywhere? Hopefully you can see enough information about the schema and what I'm attempting to do with the code below:

Edit: Thank you to the person who tagged this with relational division, you may have given me the clue that I needed!

```
select distinct product_name, size_option 
from product p
join available_in a on p.product_id = a.product_id
join sells s on p.product_id = s.product_id
join sizes si on si.sizes_id = a.sizes_id
order by size_option desc;

select product_id 
from sells s
join store_location st on st.store_location_id = s.store_location_id
where ???

select count(store_location_id)
from store_location
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sorry do you mean raw table data or data from a query? I'm hesitant to fill up too much space with data. I'll start with this but can add more. There are 5 locations, but it's better if I can determine the number of locations dynamically.

Comment: I added the relational-division-tag. Click on it, and you might get a few ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I read up on relational division and was able to come up with the answer:

```
select distinct product_name, size_option 
from product p
join available_in a on p.product_id = a.product_id
join sells s on p.product_id = s.product_id
join sizes si on si.sizes_id = a.sizes_id
join store_location st on st.store_location_id = s.store_location_id
where s.product_id in (select x.product_id 
from sells x)
group by product_name, size_option
having count(*) = (select count(*) from store_location)
order by size_option desc;
```

It works! I appreciate the clue :)